# Can I execute SELECT queries without repeating myself?

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to execute query from the second method without repeating all the stuff above?
Or should I merge everything into one function?

```
public function selectAd()
    {
        $query = "
            SELECT category,title,content,date_added from ads
        ";
        $stmt = $this->getConnection()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        if ($count > 0) {
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                echo '<div class="result">';

                echo "Title: <b>".$row['title']."</b>";
                echo "<h6>Category:".ucfirst($row['category'])."</h6>"
                .$row['content']."<br>".
                "Date: ".$row['date_added'];

                echo '</div>';
                echo "<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<u><br>Nothing to show yet</u>";

        }
    }

    public function randomAds()
    {
        $query = "
        SELECT * FROM ads ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
        ";
        // steps from method above

    }
```

Comment: Why can't you isolate the parts that you need to execute twice in a single method anyway? You already know how to write methods, so I'm not sure what exactly are you asking. Tangentially, `Order by Rand` is a horrible idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
public function WriteOutAds($doShowThemAll)
{
   $query = 'SELECT category, title,content, date_added FROM ads';
   if ($doShowThemAll==false)
      $query .= ' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5'; //Display only 5 random ones
   //perform your query
   //do emit the result
}
```